# ReactJs dúvida sobre nomenclaturas

Tags: javascript, java, react

Olá,

Estou estudando o ReactJs e estou com uma dúvida referente a nomenclatura das funções.

Vejo nos tutoriais e nos post o pessoal colocar sempre:

handleClick; handleSend

O que é esse handle? E Usar?

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tradução de "handle" seria "manusear", este termo é utilizado quando você quer vincular uma determinada programação (função) a algum evento do seu sistema (ex: "handleClick" seria a programação executada quando um determinado elemento é clicado).

Essa nomenclatura não é obrigatória, você pode usar os nomes que achar melhor. O que você precisa manter é o padrão "camelCase" na hora de nomear estas funções. Por exemplo, você não poderia ter uma função chamada handlesend, o correto seria "handleSend"

Aqui tem um link explicando melhor como funciona isso:

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: É porque gosto de usar assim: salvarProduto - editarProduto - excluirProduto. Assim identifico mas rápido qual função esta sendo chamada

Comment: Boa resposta Bins,complementando também, recomendo que veja o tutorial do Macoratti [link](Http://www.macoratti.net/18/08/react_intro10.htm)